# Refund payment by order line item ID

Tags: square-connect

Can I refund an Order/Payment by specifying the the `uid` of the `OrderLineItem` instead of specifying a `Money`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not via the API, but you could via the Dashboard or POS application. The API currently does not support itemized refunds.

https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/refunds-api/refund-payment